# How to Detect IHttpActionResult Status Code in $http/Restangular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, restangular

I have a typical Web API 2 POST method returning `IHttpActionResult`

```
public IHttpActionResult PostSomething(string someStringParam)
```

If some criteria is met I return this:

```
return BadRequest("you are request sux l0l!!1!");
```

This gets picked up by the error section of the `$http` or `Restangular` call:

```
            .error(function(err) {
                //pop failure notification or something
            });
```

Edit: By "error", I mean the second function in

```
makeSomeDatabaseCall.then(function(resp){}, function(err){})
```

How do I check that the response type was "Bad Request" (or "Conflct" or whatever) and that the message is exactly (or whatever string constant):

> "you are request sux l0l!!1!"

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can dig down the result like this for example :

```
private IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (result.Errors != null)
                {
                    foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                    }
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

By the way this snippet is for asp identity feature

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will take a look at it in detail later.

Answer (score 0):

The XMLHttpRequest object is the first argument in an Error Function.

```
   .error(function(xhr, status) {
                     alert(xhr.status);
                });
```